# modprobe on my Ubuntu machine: invalid option -- 'l'

Tags: modprobe

I was reading the modprobe manual:
https://linux.die.net/man/8/modprobe

So I tried the -l flag on a few different Ubuntu machines:
18.04, 20.04.3

After getting:

```
modprobe: invalid option -- 'l'
```

I noticed that indeed "-l" is missing when running **modprobe -h**.

If it helps, **modprobe -V** gives the following version number:

```
mod version 27
+XZ -ZLIB +LIBCRYPTO -EXPERIMENTAL
```

Can someone shed some light - how can I get modporbe with "-l" flag?

Comment: I updaed the link. try now

Comment: Don't use some random website for manpages - Ubuntu has its own: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/modprobe.8.html